# Trouble with Drop shadows exported from Google Slides to Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Using Mac Powerpoint 2016 with Google slides.

I have a slide in Google Slides that has text with a drop shadow on it.  This text is set to animate in by paragraph and when I export as a PPT document and open it in Powerpoint, the shadows appear before the text when running the presentation.  So when the slide first appears and there should be no text on it, there is just the shadows of all the text.  Then as the animation progresses, each line of actual text appears and eventually the slide looks correct once all the text is visible.

How can I get drop shadows in animated text blocks to behave properly when presenting from Powerpoint?

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in some versions of PPT for Windows that exactly fits your description. IIRC, you'd see it if text shadowing was applied via the (legacy/older) text paragraph formatting UI vs applied using the newer effects choices.  I forget exactly where you'd find each on the Mac version but basically, if the shadow option is an on/off toggle, it should be OFF.  If the shadow feature has lots of options (offset, direction, etc), that's the one to use.

Comment: Interesting, I'll dig in and look for this.  For now I just left shadows OFF anything in Google that I was planning to animate, and then I added the shadows within PPT instead.  Worked fine but added extra labor.  I did notice two different types of shadows, one under "format shape" in the format pane, and one directly on the ribbon under "Shape format".  Talk about confusing.  Thanks for the tip.